# Socket.io - is using multiple function arguments bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and have noticed that in general when multiple parameters need to be sent, they are sent in a single object.
(`socket.emit('message name', {arg1: ..., arg2: ...})`)

However, I have also noticed that passing multiple arguments in the function appears to work.
(`socket.emit('message name', arg1, arg2)`)

Is there any disadvantage of emitting messages with multiple arguments?

Comment: preference, I tend to use an object like your first, also makes it much cleaner and easy to follow when using ack's, also I've never used spaces in the event name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no disadvantage to using either option. It's just a matter of preference. Both are supported in the [Socket.io documentation](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack)